# Python mapbox showing blank map in Jupyter

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox

I have a problem about not showing show Mapbox in Jupyter.

I check if it works via `https://api.mapbox.com/?access_token=myaccesstoken` it always returns `{"api":"mapbox"}`

I updated token many times but nothing changed. How can I fix it?

Here is my code snippet.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go    
import plotly.io as pio              
import plotly.express as px

access_token = 'my-mapbox-token'
px.set_mapbox_access_token(access_token)

fig = px.density_mapbox(...)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":30,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to pass the token with your first update_layout() call, in which you should set your map style:

```
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="dark", mapbox_accesstoken=token)
```

See this example for reference:

https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-layers/

-> Go to example "Dark tiles from Mapbox service.."

Comment: Can you post your code, in which you have tried it?